# while retrieving the data from MySQL DB by using oracle connector ion spotfire we are getting below report

Tags: mysql, spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

Data connection

An exception was thrown by the data connection.

Exception text:
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection has been disabled. ---> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.33-log]Lost connection to MySQL server during query
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ConnectionIsAlive(Exception innerException)
at System.DataData connection

An exception was thrown by the data connection.

Exception text:
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection has been disabled. ---> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.33-log]Lost connection to MySQL server during query
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ConnectionIsAlive(Exception innerException)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleErrorNoThrow(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Read()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.MySqlAdapterConnection.QueryExecution(SqlQuery query, CommandType commandType, String queryString, OdbcParameter[] parameters, IList`1 storedProcedureColumns, QueryResultWriter resultWriter, NativeQueryExecutionDiagnostics executionDiagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.MySqlAdapterConnection.<>c__DisplayClass67_0.<ExecuteQueryCommon>b__1(NativeQueryExecutionDiagnostics executionDia) at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Access.QueryExecution.QueryTrackerService.ExecuteQuery(QueryExecutionInfo queryExecutionInfo, QueryExecutor queryExecutor, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.MySqlAdapterConnection.ExecuteQueryCommon(SqlQuery query, CommandType commandType, String queryString, OdbcParameter[] parameters, IList`1 storedProcedureColumns, QueryResultWriter resultWriter, IDictionary`2 logContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.MySqlAdapterConnection.ExecuteTextQuery(SqlQuery query, AdapterDataSchema schema, QueryResultWriter resultWriter, IDictionary`2 logContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.MySqlAdapterConnection.ExecuteQueryCore(SqlQuery query, AdapterDataSchema schema, QueryResultWriter resultWriter, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IDictionary`2 logContext) at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Access.Adapters.DataAdapterConnection.ExecuteQuery(SqlQuery query, AdapterDataSchema schema, QueryResultWriter resultWriter, IDictionary`2 logContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Access.Adapters.DataAdapter.TryExecuteQuery(IDataAdapterExecutionContext executionContext, AdapterCredentialsValue credentials, SqlQuery query, AdapterDataSchema schema, QueryResultWriter resultWriter, IDictionary`2 logContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Access.Adapters.DataAccessDataSourceLink.<>c__DisplayClass91_1.b__1(CancellationToken token)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Access.Adapters.DataAccessDataSourceLink.<>c__DisplayClass88_0.g__Execute|1()

We tried to reinstalled the ODBC driver in machine but still we are getting error.